# How to specify the width of a column in mdDataTable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using [this](https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable) to create a material table in Angular.

Following is my html :-

```html
    <md-tab label="Tests">
      <mdt-table sortable-columns="true"
      animate-sort-icon="true">
      <mdt-header-row>
        <mdt-column align-rule="left">Date</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="center">Subject</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="center">Chapter</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="center">Test Name</mdt-column>
      </mdt-header-row>
      <mdt-row ng-repeat="x in tests">
        <mdt-cell>{{x.attempted}}</mdt-cell>
        <mdt-cell>{{x.subject}}</mdt-cell>
        <mdt-cell>{{x.chapter}}</mdt-cell>
        <mdt-cell>{{x.name}}</mdt-cell>
      </mdt-row>
    </mdt-table>
```

I need to define a specific width for the first column (i-e Date) which I am unable to do so.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... The first visible column is at index 2.  Hope it helps.

```
mdt-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Insert your desired width and format - I actually used 7vw.